# jQuery: Set css background-color for an ID + Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, variables

I am trying to set a background color for an ID + Variable but I can't figure it out. There must be something really small that I am not aware of.

Here is what I have:

```
var abc = $dialog.data( "url" );
alert(abc)
```

This Alerts: **item1**

```
var cde = '#' + abc
alert(cde)
```

This Alerts: **#item1**

So far so good. Now, I'm trying to change the background for that ID.
So:

This works:

```
$(body).css('background-color', 'black');
```

This **doesn't**:

```
cde.css('background-color', 'black');
$(cde).css('background-color', 'black');
$("#" + abc).css('background-color', 'black');
```

All are in the same function.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: did you tried only one of them ???

Comment: What type of element should `#item1` refer to?

Comment: Yes, I thought people would be able to realize that when I wrote all of the 3 options, I meant that I used one every time.

Comment: @JamesAllardice It's a <li> .. If I just do $("#item1").css('background-color', 'black'); it works fine.

Comment: @jQuerybeast - Can you make a jsfiddle that replicates your problem? I can't see anything at first glance that would cause `$(cde).css(...)` to not work.

Comment: I tested `var abc = 'item1'; $('#' + abc).css('background', 'black');` in jsFiddle and it worked, so there might be something elsewhere that  you are overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I see that your code is not working is because the value that you pass to jQuery (namely cde or "#" + abc) is not of type "String".

You can do some test for that :

```
var test = "#item1";
alert(test === cde);
alert(typeof(cde));
```

If the type is not string, then you could simply do :

```
$(cde.toString()).css('background-color', 'black');
```

Comment: When you concatenate a variable with a string literal you get a string. So `"#" + abc` will result in a String. (As an aside, `typeof` is an operator, not a method, so you shouldn't put the operand in parentheses.)

Comment: @jQuerybeast - What does `alert(typeof cde);` say? I don't see how it can be anything other than a String since you concatenate it with a string literal (the "#").

Comment: Just FYI, I never said that this was logic, just said the only reason I can see for that jQuery calls to fail is that the passed parameter is not a string. I'm really curious about the type of the variable too!

Answer (score 3):

If you try this, does it work?

```
$('#item1').css('background-color', 'black');
```

Comment: Same here. It does work. But not like this `$('#item'+id)`

Comment: By testing it the way you suggest, I found the bug.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
How about forcing it to a string like this?

```
$("" + cde).css('background-color', 'black');
```

Comment: was kinda hoping you just missed that, otherwise the code looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `alert()`, use `console.log()`.

`alert()` has a habit of automatically calling `.toString()` on objects, and also flattening arrays.

I expect what's happening is that your variable `abc` is not actually a string, so what you probably have is the result of:

```
'#' + abc.toString()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementById('item1').style.backgroundColor='black';
```

this always works!